# Anaconda Prompt Error : ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda but when I try opening the Anaconda Prompt I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 174, in main
    from ..exceptions import handle_exception

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ._vendor.auxlib.entity import EntityEncoder

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\entity.py", line 249, in <module>
    from .collection import AttrDict, frozendict, make_immutable

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .compat import isiterable, iteritems, odict, text_type

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._vendor.five import WhateverIO as StringIO, with_metaclass

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\_vendor\five.py", line 66, in <module>
    SYSTEM = platform.system()

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\platform.py", line 1265, in system
    return uname()[0]

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\platform.py", line 1161, in uname
    release,version,csd,ptype = win32_ver()

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\platform.py", line 637, in win32_ver
    maj, min, build = _get_real_winver(*winver[:3])

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\platform.py", line 569, in _get_real_winver
    from ctypes import (c_buffer, POINTER, byref, create_unicode_buffer,

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```